# User Storage gets clear when I am switching intent using Event Input

Tags: java, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am using Action on google Java client library in my webhook code.How to retrieve data from user storage after switching to an event.

I am setting some value in user storage and switched to an custom event using EventInput from my webhook.After I triggered another Intent, the user storage gets clear and it is empty in ActionRequest.

How to retrieve data from user storage after switching to an custom event?

Comment: Me too. I have the same issue, but with Node.js. In my case, after I stored some data in user storage, I made a session finished. After that, I opened it again and welcome intent seems to be ok because I checked the inside of user storage. But after switching to another intent from welcome intent, user storage data gets all cleared.